# TESTNG_HOME Environment Variable not present in system, But testNG suite is still running

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I have a Selenium-Java-TestNG-Maven suite. Is it mandatory to set TESTNG_HOME environment variable and Set the CLASSPATH environment variable to point to the TestNG jar location ? 
Because i have not done both of the above ,but maven is running my testNG suite without issues.

Comment: TESTNG_HOME where have you read that ? The classpath is created during the maven build by maven-surefire/failsafe if you have defined a dependency to testng artifact ... ?